# Groovy criteria query

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain model that looks like this

```
Category 1 ------- * Type 1 ------- * Expense
```

Or in English "An expense has a type, and each type belongs to a category". I want to write a Criteria query that will find all expenses in a particular category. I tried both this

```
Expense.withCriteria {
    eq('type.category', someCategoryInstance)
}
```

and this

```
Expense.withCriteria {
    type {
        eq('category', someCategoryInstance)
    }    
}
```

But neither of them work, what am I missing?

### Update

I've been asked to show the domain classes, so here they are:

```
public class Category {

    String description
    static hasMany = [types: Type]  
}

public class Type {

    String description
    static hasMany = [expenses: Expense]
    static belongsTo = [category: Category]
}

public class Expense {

    static belongsTo = [type: Type]

    Date date
    String description
    float amount
}
```

Comment: The second one looks right to me, I swear I've done it that way before. Can you maybe put the basic structure of your domain classes in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the associations are declared, the type table might not be joined in to the query.  You can explicitly tell it to join with a `join` in your criteria.

```
Expense.withCriteria {
    join('type')
    type {
        eq('category', someCategoryInstance)
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is probably why the default sort order in `static mapping` for an association doesn't work sometimes as well, I'm guessing (since it sometimes creates a join table for the association)?

Comment: The domain class associations looks ok to me.  I wonder if there is a namespace collision between your Category class and groovy.lang.Category?